# Can't create file in Ada 95

Tags: file, ada

I'm trying to follow a standard reference for opening files but running into a constraint_error at the line when I call Ada.Text_IO.Create(). It says "range check failed". Any help appreciated, here's the code:

```
WITH Ada.Text_IO;
WITH Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
USE Ada.Text_IO;
USE Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

PROCEDURE FileManip IS

   --Variables
   Start_Int : Integer;
   Stop_Int : Integer;
   Max_Length : Integer;

   --Output File
   MaxName : CONSTANT Positive := 80;
   SUBTYPE NameRange IS Positive RANGE 1..MaxName;

   OutFileName : String(NameRange) := (OTHERS => '#');
   OutNameLength : NameRange;
   OutData : File_Type;

   --Array
   TYPE Chain_Array IS ARRAY(1..500) OF Integer;
   Sum : Integer := 1;
BEGIN

--Inputs
   Ada.Text_IO.Put(Item => "Enter a starting Integer: ");
   Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get(Item => Start_Int);
   Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
   Ada.Text_IO.Put(Item => "Enter a stopping Integer: ");
   Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get(Item => Stop_Int);
   Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
   Ada.Text_IO.Put(Item => "Enter a Maximum Length to search: ");
   Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get(Item => Max_Length);
   Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
   Ada.Text_IO.Put(Item => "Enter a output file name > ");
   Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line(
      Item => OutFileName,
      Last => OutNameLength);
   Ada.Text_IO.Create(
      File => OutData,
      Mode => Ada.Text_IO.Out_File,
      Name => OutFileName(1..OutNameLength));
   Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
```

Comment: Can we see the exact error message please?

Comment: As an aside, you have a use clause for each package and then write the full name of each subprogram call. You don't have to do both, although using full names is good when starting out.

Answer (score 3):

Likely it isn't the `create` that is giving you that problem, but an array range check on `OutFileName(1..OutNameLength)`.

For that to happen, either 1 or OutNameLength would need to be out of the range specified for OutFileName. Since that was defined as `RANGE 1..MaxName` (via NameRange), we know it isn't the 1, so the culprit must be `OutNameLength`.

Looking around, it looks like you get that value from the `Last` parameter of a `Get_Line`. There is one situation where you can get a 0 out of that parameter: when you read a blank line. So my guess is that is what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

For each `Integer` you read, `Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get` uses the default Width of zero, so it ["skips any leading blanks, line terminators, or page terminators, then reads a plus sign if present or (for a signed type only) a minus sign if present, then reads the longest possible sequence of characters matching the syntax of a numeric literal without a point."](http://www.adaic.com/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-10-8.html) A subsequent `Ada.Text_IO.New_Line` leaves the line terminator there for `Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line` to trip over, and zero is not within `NameRange`. Instead use [`Ada.Text_IO.Skip_Line`](http://www.adaic.com/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-10-5.html). For example,

```
Ada.Text_IO.Put(Item => "Enter a starting Integer: ");
Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get(Item => Start_Int);
Ada.Text_IO.Skip_Line;
Ada.Text_IO.Put(Item => "Enter a stopping Integer: ");
Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get(Item => Stop_Int);
Ada.Text_IO.Skip_Line;
Ada.Text_IO.Put(Item => "Enter a Maximum Length to search: ");
Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get(Item => Max_Length);
Ada.Text_IO.Skip_Line;
...
```

Comment: Get reads "up to a line terminator" only if a non-zero value of Width is specified (refer to the linked reference).  If Width is zero, the default case, then Integer_Text_IO.Get "reads the longest possible sequence of characters matching the syntax of a numeric literal without a point".

Answer (score 1):

Tangentially related...

A common practice for acquiring interactive input is to avoid using the "Integer_Text_IO" and related packages for Gets, and instead use Get_Line and then do a conversion. E.g.:

```
   S : String(1..200);
   L : Natural;

   ...

   Ada.Text_IO.Put(Item => "Enter a starting Integer: ");
   Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line(Item => S, Last => L);
   Start_Int := Integer'Value(S(1..L));
```

This approach makes it easier to check for a user entering a C/R (L = 0), and while the numeric Get procedures only read characters so long as they conform to the syntax of a numeric literal, up to the end-of-line, by grabbing the whole line with Get_Line, you avoid having to deal with the end-of-line issue and can make sure that *all* of what was entered was a numeric literal (by catching the Constraint_Error exception if one is raised when evaluating the 'Value attribute).

And although it was more of a problem with earlier Ada compilers, the Get procedures didn't always work identically on different platforms due to different systems' conventions for designating end of line, end of file, etc.  Get_Line, though, pretty much worked the same across all platforms, and so it and a subsequent string->numeric conversion was a widely recommended practice.

Comment: +1 Although tangential to the problem, this is a more reliable idiom.